# Transform - origin of image on mouse move on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I am trying to add smooth move effect on `img` when user do a `mousemove` on image parent element (here `.carousel-img`) but I can't run it properly.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('.carousel-img').on('mousemove', function(e){
  $('.carousel-img img').css({'transform-origin': ((e.pageX - $('.carousel-img img').offset().left) / $('.carousel-img img').width()) * 100 + '% ' + ((e.pageY - $('.carousel-img img').offset().top) / $('.carousel-img img').height()) * 100 +'%'});
    })
```

```css
html, body{height:100%; width:100%;}
.box{position: relative; height:100%; width:100%;}
.carousel-img {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  padding:100px;

}
.carousel-img img {
  position: relative;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="box">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x600/fff/fff">
      <div class="carousel-img">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150/ff0000/ff0000" >
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your `transform` property being declared?

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property instead of the [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property. You want to use the `translate(x,y)` to define the movement you're looking for.

You also should include a transition to your `img` selector, so that the movement is smooth. I also added some other attributes that may be useful when adding more complex animations such as translate3D types.

Check the updated snippet below.

```js
$('.carousel-img').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var translateX = ((e.pageX - $('.carousel-img img').offset().left) / $('.carousel-img img').width()) * 100;
  var translateY = ((e.pageY - $('.carousel-img img').offset().top) / $('.carousel-img img').height()) * 100;
  var translateProperty = 'translate(' + translateX + '%, ' + translateY + '%)';

$('.carousel-img img').css({
    '-webkit-transform': translateProperty,
    '-moz-transform': translateProperty,
    '-ms-transform': translateProperty,
    '-o-transform': translateProperty,
    'transform': translateProperty
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 100px;
}

.carousel-img img {
  position: relative;
  
  /* Add transition */
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  /* Default values for transition to be possible */
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="box">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x600/fff/fff">
      <div class="carousel-img">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150/ff0000/ff0000" >
      </div>
</div>
```